# How do I push to an array that is nested in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

I have been working on this for hours and can't figure it out. I have a checklist object sorted by category, and each category is an array of task objects. I am trying to allow the user to add a task to a given category array, but cannot figure it out. Each time I try to log the array, it just prints out the observer and says that '.push' is not a function.

I think the issue is dealing with using a variable to get the array because when I hard code in 'masterChecklist["General Cleaning"]', it will work. Please help!

** The example below is simplified

```js
var masterChecklist = {

    "General Cleaning": 
         [
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Empty and sanitize trash bins'},
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Clean mirrors and windows'},
         ],

     "Home Exterior": 
         [
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Wipe and clean all furniture'},
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Empty the trash bins'},
         ],
}

SaveTaskDetails("Dust", "Make sure to get the shelves", "General Cleaning")

function SaveTaskDetails(name, notes, category) {
  var newTask = {
    name: name,
    notes: notes,
    cleaned: false
  }
  var category = masterChecklist[category].push(newTask)
}

console.log(masterChecklist);
```

Comment: I converted your code to a runnable snippet, and it works without error.

Comment: It will only work if you're saving to an existing category. If you need to be able to create new categories, the function needs to check whether `masterChecklist[category]` already exists, and add it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const masterChecklist = {'General Cleaning': [{ cleaned: false, notes: '', name: 'Empty and sanitize trash bins' },{ cleaned: false, notes: '', name: 'Clean mirrors and windows' },],'Home Exterior': [{ cleaned: false, notes: '', name: 'Wipe and clean all furniture' },{ cleaned: false, notes: '', name: 'Empty the trash bins' }]}

const SaveTaskDetails = (name, notes, category) => {
  if (!masterChecklist[category]) {
    masterChecklist[category] = []
  }

  masterChecklist[category].push({ name, notes, cleaned: false })
}

SaveTaskDetails('Dust', 'Make sure to get the shelves', 'General Cleaning')
SaveTaskDetails('Dust', 'Make sure to get the shelves', 'New Category')

console.log(masterChecklist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the category exists, if not you should assign an empty array and add into it.(I assumed on my code that the category does not exist because it gives an error when the category does not exist.)(By the way I highly recommend you to use const and let instead of var)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Should Not Use Spaces In Object Key, use `_` instead

you can check your variable before doing any operation with `typeof` operator

**example**

```
var masterChecklist = {

    "General Cleaning": 
         [
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Empty and sanitize trash bins'},
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Clean mirrors and windows'},
         ],

     "Home Exterior": 
         [
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Wipe and clean all furniture'},
             {cleaned: false, notes: "", name: 'Empty the trash bins'},
         ],
}

SaveTaskDetails("Dust", "Make sure to get the shelves", "General Cleaning")
SaveTaskDetails("Dust", "Make sure to get the shelves", "New Category")

function SaveTaskDetails(name, notes, category) {
  var newTask = {
    name: name,
    notes: notes,
    cleaned: false
  }
  var selectedCatg = typeof masterChecklist[category] == "undefined"?masterChecklist[category] = []:masterChecklist[category]
  selectedCatg.push(newTask)
}

console.log(masterChecklist);
```